# Correct way of using node-postgres select with IN clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I am trying to workout how to pass in a comma sepated string of values into a postgres select within **in** clause query using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) but unfortunately can't seem to get it working and can't find any examples.

I have the following code:

```
function getUser() {
  let inList = "'qwerty', 'qaz'";

  const result = await pgPool.query("SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE info IN ($1)", [inList]);  
  if (result.rowCount == 1) return result.rows.map(row => row.name)
  return false
}
```

Basically want the end result query to process:

`SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE info IN ('qwerty', 'qaz')`

Unsure if this is actually the correct way of doing this with pgPool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way is in the FAQ on Github --> https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values

You should be able to do it that way :

```
 pgPool.query("SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE info = ANY ($1)", [jsArray], ...);
```